# TypeScript: import external module from node_modules

Tags: typescript

There is a npm module `one-two-three` for example.
It contains TS files `index.ts` (the main) and `functions.ts`.

functions.ts:

```
export interface IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

export function sum(a: IPoint, b: IPoint): IPoint {
    return {
        x: a.x + b.x,
        y: a.y + b.y
    };
}
```

index.ts:

```
import functions = require("./functions");

export var sum: typeof functions.sum = functions.sum;
```

compile:

```
tsc --module commonjs --declaration index.ts
```

Files are created: `index.js`, `index.d.ts`, `functions.js` and `functions.d.ts`.
Ok.

There is another library that dependent on `one-two-three`.

```
npm install --save one-two-three
```

I want to include dependence and use it and the interface from `functions.ts`.

```
import mo = require("one-two-three");
```

Error `Cannot find external module 'one-two-three'`.

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/one-two-three/index.d.ts" />
import mo = require("one-two-three");
```

No reaction.

```
import mo = require("./node_modules/one-two-three");
```

Fail.

```
declare var require;

var mo = require("one-two-three");
```

It compiles successfully.
But there is no type checking.
Can write: `mo.unknownFunction()` and it will be compiled.
Can not use interfaces.

How to make the above-described in the correct?

**UPDATE**

I have achieved the desired behavior follows.
Edit d.ts files.

functions.d.ts:

```
declare module "one-two-three.functions" {
    export interface IPoint {
        x: number;
        y: number;
    }
    export function sum(a: IPoint, b: IPoint): IPoint;
}
```

index.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="./functions.d.ts" />

declare module "one-two-three" {
    import functions = require("one-two-three.functions");
    export var sum: typeof functions.sum;
}
```

Using it:

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/one-two-three/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="node_modules/one-two-three/functions.d.ts" />

import oneTwoThree = require("one-two-three");
import functions = require("one-two-three.functions");
import IPoint = functions.IPoint;

function delta(a: IPoint, b: IPoint): number {
    var dx: number = a.x - b.x,
        dy: number = a.y - b.y;
    return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}

var point1: IPoint = {x: 10, y: 20},
    point2: IPoint = {x: 5, y: 5};

console.log(oneTwoThree.sum(point1, point2));
console.log(delta(point1, point2));
```

Success.
But we have to do double duty. 
Write code and separately describe the interface.

Is there a way to generate the correct d.ts?
The problem is that the d.ts should describe the module with internal syntax (`module {}`).
But source file is CommonJS module.
It does not have the section `module`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/one-two-three/index.d.ts" />
import mo = require("one-two-three");
```

> No reaction.

It should work.

A file `.d.ts` in TypeScript is like a file `.h` in C. It's normal to use it when a dependency is imported from another project or sub-project.

If the file `your-project/node_modules/one-two-three/index.d.ts` isn't written correctly, I suggest to copy it to `your-project/one-two-three.d.ts`, and then fix the copy. Using the module name as file name makes the `/// <reference` optional. Just write:

```
import mo = require("one-two-three");
```

Comment: But does not work :(

As I understand, d.ts file must have follow view: module "one-two-three" {...}

But it compiled as --module commonjs and contains just functions without `module` statement.

Comment: Can you fix the file `.d.ts`?

Comment: Yes, I can do it, but I would not want.
I added UPDATE to the question.

Comment: Ok, it is clear.
I will write d.ts files manually.
Thank you, Tarh!