# Require custom module with npm and typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, typescript

Lets play with 2 projects: *main-project* and *lib-project* both of them are written in typescript, and then using *gulp* compiled to common javascript.
Our goal is require *lib-project* in *main-project*.

***lib-project***

```
|-- package.json
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- dist
   |-- index.js
   |-- a.js
| src
   |-- index.ts
   |-- a.ts
```

We have created those js compiling them from their ts; lets take a quick look to them (we have index because we'll want eventually so many exports)

***index.ts***

```
import a = require('./a');
module.exports = {A: a.A};
```

***a.ts***

```
export class A {
  field: string;
  constructor(aField: string) {this.field = aField;}
  toString() : string {return `A: ${this.field}`;}
}
```

***index.js***

```
var a = require('./a');
module.exports = { A: a.A };
```

***a.js***

```
var A = (function () {
    function A(aField) {
        this.field = aField;
    }
    A.prototype.toString = function () {
        return "A: " + this.field;
    };
    return A;
})();
exports.A = A;
```

---

That was the introduction; now, I push it to a git repo and require it as a *dependency* in the *package.json* and run `npm install`, our *main-project* is:

**main-project**

```
|-- package.json
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- node_modules
    |--lib-project
       |-- dist
         |-- index.js
         |-- a.js
    |--node
       |...
 |--src
    |--app.ts
```

Is in *app.ts* where this is failing: **`cannot find module lib-project`**

***app.ts***

```
import a = require('lib-project');
var foo = new a.A('HELLO');
console.log(foo.toString());
```

---

What have I tried?

1. move the index.js of the lib-project to the root folder
2. In the package.json, set the field `"main": "dist/index.js"`
3. `import a = require('node_modules/lib-project/dist/index');`
4. `import a = require('../node_modules/lib-project/dist/index');`
5. Multiple version of the tsc (typescript compiler)

Any help appreciated :)

---

**EDIT**

***package.json***

```
{
  "name": "lib-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "description here",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also paste in the `package.json` for `lib-project`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're missing is a `lib-project.d.ts` file in the root of the lib project. This will fill the role of what you already have in index.ts, but you'll need to tweak it slightly to fill this role

```
|-- package.json
|-- gulpfile.js
|-- lib-project.d.ts <-- formerly index.ts
|-- dist
   |-- a.js
| src
   |-- a.ts
```

Where lib-project.d.ts would look like this:

```
declare module 'lib-project' {
  import a = require('./a');
  export = {A: a.A};
}
```

Then when consuming this you can use:

```
import {A} from 'lib-project';
```

You can reference what I've done here for exporting: https://github.com/Brocco/ng-bridge

And importing too: https://github.com/Brocco/ng-bridge-samples/blob/master/app/app.ts#L1

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer to: [TypeScript: import external module from node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29653735/typescript-import-external-module-from-node-modules)

**Gist:**
Compile using `tsc --module commonjs --declaration index.ts` and then use the following while import:

```
/// <reference path="node_modules/lib-project/index.d.ts" />
import a = require('lib-project');
```