# Typescript declare javascript external modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

So, I'm new to TypeScript and I wanted to convert a really small NodeJS project I was doing in plain JavaScript to TypeScript. In that project, I use some npm modules that have a definition under the `@types` scope, but others don't.

So, I figured I'd create these declarations for myself in my project, without having to change those third-party modules. However, no matter where I put the `.d.ts` file, TypeScript does not seem to recognize it.

**src/typings.d.ts**

```
import stream = require( 'stream' );
import http = require( 'http' );

declare module "flatten" {
    function flatten ( ...arrays : any[] ) : any[];

    export = flatten;
}

declare module "got" {
    //...
}
```

And then when I try to use the module flatten, for instance:

**src/manager.ts**

```
import flatten = require( 'flatten' );
//...
```

I get the error:

```
src/manager.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'flatten'.
```

My **tsconfig.json** looks like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "lib/" 
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Require custom module with npm and typescript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32222010/require-custom-module-with-npm-and-typescript)

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. In this case, the external modules are not mine, so I can't just create a file in them.

Comment: Then maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29653735/215552. They are basically demonstrating the same error. You'll need to adapt them to your specific circumstances. There are a number of possible duplicates in the Related section; this is not an uncommon error.